Does it make sense to create a confidence interval referencing the Z-distribution if we know the population distribution isn't normal?
I'm taking an introductory statistics course for my biology degree and, when learning about generating the confidence interval for the population mean, I started wondering if it'd make sense to do so in the case that we knew that the original population isn't normally distributed. To my knowledge, the CLT doesn't have any utility in such a case, because what we care about is creating a confidence interval whose assumed chances agree with the original probability distribution, that of the population.
Am I missing something? If not, what would be the procedure for evaluating the correctedness of referencing such or such theoretical distribution to construct the confidence interval?

Why not explore this at the Statistics stack?

Sorry, you're right! I didn't know there was one.
